# How to render user given material with some resolution and have access to rendered data?

Tags: python, c++, api, maya

I would love to generate some geometry from b/w material data (say from some user given [Substance](http://www.allegorithmic.com/products/database) Hightmap). So I wonder if it is possible (because I sadly do not see how from [API](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2014/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/)), and how to render user given material with some resolution and have access to rendered data (as to an array of color values)?

Comment: So, you want to use a displacement map?

Answer (score 1):

For the specific case of a heightmap, see:

http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/index.html?url=files/Surface_Relief__Connect_a_texture_as_a_displacement_map.htm,topicNumber=d30e632762

For other situations, you would have to render the image and read it using an image processing library. Some popular ones you can access through maya Python are [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), [LibTiff](https://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/) and [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php)  although in both cases you'll need to get the right binaries for your processor and OS.  I believe the latter two are also available with C++ bindings